# Resize matrix in MathNet

Tags: matrix, mathnet-numerics

If I have a matrixA that is 1x5 with all values = 1.0, and I want to resize it to 1x8 by having other elements as 0's, how do I do it?

```
Matrix<double> A = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(1, 5, 1.0);
```

In other words, is it possible to multiple or carry out any operations on 2 different size matrices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in a matrix, rather than the vector you originally described, here's an example of SetSubMatrix:

```
    Matrix<double> SubMatrix = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(2, 2, 0.186);
    Matrix<double> BigMatrix = Matrix<double>.Build.Dense(3, 3);
    BigMatrix.SetSubMatrix(1, 1, SubMatrix);
```

Note you can place the submatrix anywhere inside the larger matrix. And here's the output where I placed the submatrix at (1,1) in the BigMatrix. And yes, it does work in MathNet if you know what function to use:

[image]

and here it's placed at (0,0):

[image]

Comment: what library are you using ? Is this Accord.NET ?

Comment: Did you even look at the documentation? These are matrix operations. Linear Algebra. Come on guy do a little work here.

Comment: MathNet documentation ? I have been searching for this all the while. Never hit anything as such. Let me look into it again.

Comment: I am so sorry. Thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for ever since yesterday. Even tried various other libs like Accord.NET etc. You are a savior! Do you mind combining both your answers, both of them are relevant and correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a 1 by X, it's a Vector. So one option is to make a second vector (ie, 1x8), and then use the

```
void CopySubVectorTo(Vector<T> destination, int sourceIndex, int targetIndex, int count)
```

to copy the non-zero elements of the 1X5 to the larger vector, or

```
void CopyTo(Vector<T> target)
```

Comment: Not necessarily a vector, consider a 2x2 to be expanded to 3x3 where the extra row and column elementsof 3x3 are 0's

Comment: The point is the same. You can make a second, larger matrix and copy the non-zero values from the smaller to the larger.

Comment: doesnt work with MathNet. I have already tried that, the error is matrix dimensions do not agree.

Comment: If you're trying to do this to a matrix, not a vector, try

Comment: void SetSubMatrix(int rowIndex, int columnIndex, Matrix<T> subMatrix)
Copies the values of a given matrix into a region in this matrix.